# Cannot translate a whole series of Japanese characters while it works when I take only one line

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am currently building a web scraper to grab japanese words from articles, put them in a dataframe and them translate them.

I use the Translator object from googletrans package in order to translate the characters that are in the columns named "kanji".

When I do this:

```
translator = Translator()
translator.translate(df["kanji"][5]).text
```

I get 'Middle school students', which is perfect.

However, when I try to generalize that to the whole series:

```
df["kanji"].apply(translator.translate)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

I don't understand why it does not work. Could you please provide some help?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: df['kanji'] looks like it has different string size inside

Comment: I found the solution. The column was not well cleaned, it had some non string elements. After some extra cleaning, it worked. Thank you!